# Detecting page unload in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, global-variables, onbeforeunload, persist, rootscope

I have a javascript object which I need global to my angularjs application. When the application is about to be unloaded (due to a page refresh or some other scenario), I would like to persist the object to browser storage. I believe adding the object to $rootScope would fulfill the first requirement of making the object global, but writing the object to storage during the `onbeforeunload` event, would require access to the $rootScope variable. Is it possible to detect a page unload event in angularjs?

Comment: have you considered using something like https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage or https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it, but I also suggest avoiding `$rootScope` as global state is discouraged, and you might also wrap `localStorage` in a service so that it can be injected and mocked for testing.

```
.run([
  '$window',
  '$rootScope',
  function($window, $rootScope) {
    $window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
      localStorage.myValue = $rootScope.myValue;
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. And would the event for page completed loading be `load`?

Comment: @user1491636 I don't think you should be using that event. If you want something to run at the beginning of your Angular app, just put it in a `run` block as in my example here.

Comment: Your solution does not solve the problem, because even by clicking cancel it is called.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Clicking cancel on what? Nothing in the post or my answer involves any buttons, that I know of.